# How to optimize the connection of Bluetooth A2DP in iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, a2dp

I'm developing an app for smart device with Bluetooth. I know that it's easy to directly connect Bluetooth A2DP in the app in Android, but if you want to do this in iOS, it's not very easy for us to do it. I mean that it's not the technical point, because the app I'm developing must be distributed in App Store!

Now:Every time, I should remind the users to connect the Bluetooth A2DP in iOS system settings,if the Bluetooth A2DP is not connected with the smart device,but this often make the users confused the it's a little complicated for the users.This is the point.I know that we can use private API of iOS to connect Bluetooth A2DP in the app,but it's very dangerous,because it will be rejected by Apple,because my app need to be distributed in App Store.

So anyone can give some ideas about the optimization of Bluetooth A2DP connection in iOS?

Comment: Hello Thomas! Could you please specify the problem? Why can't you use A2DP in the iOS app? What is preventing you from doing it? Why do you want to optimize the connection? Is it not optimal? Does it have some issues?

Comment: Hello,friend.I edit my question about this.

Comment: So your company can also deal with the development of the firmware of your smart device with Bluetooth?

Comment: Yes,we have software engineer for the smart device.So what's the idea?

Comment: If you really do.you can do something from the smart device.See my answer.